# Axios interceptor disabled catching exception

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I am trying to use axios interceptor to refresh my jwt access token and retry call and I found a strange issue, if I use axios interceptor it never goes to catch clause and I cant show any error.
I also tried to use axios-auth-refresh package but same result.What I am missing here

Comment: What are you missing? I'd say [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and enough detail to receive any kind of answer.

Comment: @anothermh I have an api which is returning this {"Message":"Please verify email address and password."} with status code 401 if user entered wrong details I want to show this error message on react front end using axios but instead of going into catch its goes to then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by checking the expiration of token in request interceptor and renew it there instead of waiting for 401 error in response interceptor and renew token. It seems this piece of code was causing issue i removed response interceptor completely

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response
   }, async function (error) {
    const url = error.request.responseURL;


    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      await this.getAccessToken();      
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + TokenStorageService.getAccessToken();
      return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
   });
```

Instead I used request interceptor like this

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async request => {
        if (!TokenStorageService.HasAccessToken() || (TokenStorageService.HasAccessToken() && TokenStorageService.isTokenExpired()) && TokenStorageService.HasRefreshToken()) {

            await this.getAccessToken();
        }
        if (TokenStorageService.HasAccessToken() && !TokenStorageService.isTokenExpired()) {


            request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${TokenStorageService.getAccessToken()}`;
        }


        return request;
    },
    error => {
      Promise.reject(error);
  });
```